# getting Id from created record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

New web developer here, and I think I may be missing some very fundamental knowledge. Given the code

```
> def create
>     @post = Post.new(post_params)
>     if @post.save
>         redirect_to @post
>     else
>         render "new"
>     end   
 end
```

after saving the post, it redirects to show page, due to this "redirect_to @post", how can I do the same thing with "redirect_to: action => "show", :id => 5" I have to pass the ID now, how to retrieve the ID from @post object?

so only I can pass the Id to redirect page.

can I stop the compiler here, like debugger in js?

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you having a problem?

Comment: Also are you using a IDE like Rubymine?

Comment: yes using rubymine,after saving the post it redirect to showpage, due this "redirect_to @post", how can I do the same thing with  "redirect_to :action => "show", :id => 5" I have to pass the ID now, how to reteve the ID from @post

Comment: `redirect_to` when given an object like `@post` will redirect you to the show action of the current value of @post. So you don't need to specify any of that. It assumes you want to go to the show action for the post where id = @post.id. This is what is meant by "convention over configuration" in Rails.

Comment: is any keyword available in rails to stop the code execution like debugger point? like debugger keyword in Javascript?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp.  @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question of "I may be missing some very fundamental knowledge" yes, you might be. An object in Rails like @post is usually a database record. You can access any of it's columns in the DB by using the column name as a method:

```
@post.id
```

returns:

```
 5 #or whatever the post id is.
```

If your post table has a column of "title" you can access it with

```
@post.title
```

returns:

```
"This is an awesome post"
```

I would highly recommend you view some Ruby and some Rails tutorials. Everything in Ruby is an object. Rails uses a lot of conventions so you can do things without having to write code for it, it's already there for you. When you get into Rails ActiveRecord Relations you'll see that relations expand this to give you related table information as methods. For Example:

Post.rb

```
...
belongs_to :user
```

User.rb

```
...
has_many :posts
```

Gives you methods like:

```
@post.user   #returns the user object with all of its info
@post.user.username   #returns the value of that column for that user
@post.user.posts     #returns an array of Post objects that belong to the owner of that post.
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a `pry-byebug` gem for debugging. It's a combination REPL (Pry) and core debugger (byebug) that work very powerfully together.

Getting the `id` of a successfully saved `ActiveRecord` model is just `@post.id`, however the rails methods like `redirect_to` will take the object itself just fine, as @Beartech has mentioned, above. [The documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) shows a variety of ways to use it, for convenience:

> ```rb
> redirect_to action: "show", id: 5
> redirect_to @post
> redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
> redirect_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
> redirect_to posts_url
> redirect_to proc { edit_post_url(@post) }
> ```

Comment: thats I know, so we need to pass the Id correct that's what I am asking , now i am got it from @Beartech info